# How to remove elements in content array of  ArrayController (Ember)

Tags: ember.js

I have a model like:

```js
TestModel = Em.Object.create({
    id:'',
    name:''
})
```

and a object ArrayController like:

```js
testArrayController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function() {
        //push some object TestModel
    }
});
```

I want to remove some objects depend on id property of a object in content array. How to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use a combination of [`findProperty`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_findProperty) and [`removeObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable.html#method_removeObject), see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/rXN4E/:

```js
App.testArrayController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    removeItem: function(propName, value){
        var obj = this.findProperty(propName, value);
        this.removeObject(obj);
    }
});

App.testArrayController.removeItem('id', 42);
```

Comment: FYI:  this won't work if you are using Ember Data to fetch the data for the controller - the array is immutable.

Comment: @outside2344: I think it depends if you retrieve the data from the store with find or filter. If you get it by find, it works and then it's actually necessary...

Answer (score 4):

I had a situation where I had a table with a checkbox next to each row.

I wanted to remove each row that had been selected when a button was clicked.

Each checkbox was bound to an isSelected property on the item controller.

I used the [removeObjects](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_removeObjects) and filterProperty functions to remove the items:

```
this.removeObjects(this.filterProperty('isSelected'));
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/erIfAkU/9/edit?html,js,output) with an example.

These are the important bits:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'IndexItem',
  actions: {
    removeSelected: function() {
      this.removeObjects(this.filterProperty('isSelected'));
    }
  }
});

App.IndexItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isSelected: true
});
```